# Import text file into python3 as a string without changing the formatting in any way

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm writing an API request (with requests) that has a large payload attached to it that I want to separate into an isolated .txt file. When I import the string from the text file, it appears to change the formatting of the contents. But my API call fails when I use the imported version.

If I put the string directly into my code it prints it taking in to account the \n\r characters and formats the output nicely but if I print the string imported from the text file, it prints it as one big blob. I believe that something is different when it's imported and that's what is causing my API call to fail.

Here is a sample of the text I'm trying to place in it's own file:
`"lab:\r\n  description: ''\r\n  notes: ''\r\n  timestamp: 1595605020.8855264\r\n  title: Dev Env\r\n  version: 0.0.3\r\n"`

I'm importing the file as a string with the following code:

```
with open ('config.txt', 'r') as txtFile:
       config_payload = txtFile.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the file look like when you open it in another editor? When you print the string (with \r, \n, etc), it should look the same. Chances are, somehow the literal characters '\' and 'n' got added to the file, rather than the escaped characters \n.

Also if you are doing this in a repl,

```
>>> config_payload
```

will show up as unformatted, but

```
>>> print(config_payload)
```

will be formatted.